# Haskell Diagrams program draws circle but does not fill circle with colour

Tags: haskell, svg, haskell-diagrams

I have written the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine

main = mainWith (my_diagram :: Diagram B)

my_diagram = circle 1 # fc blue
                      # lw veryThick
                      # lc purple
                      # dashingG [0.2, 0.05] 0
```

But the program produces a white circle with black outline - no colour or dashing. Any one know what might be wrong?

I'm running in a sandbox on Haskell Platform 7.10.2 (Windows 8)

P.S. The diagrams version is 1.3 and the program generates the following SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="400.0000" stroke-opacity="1" viewBox="0 0 400 400" font-size="1" width="400.0000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" version="1.1">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <g stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-opacity="1.0" fill-opacity="0.0" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1.6" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="10.0">
    <path d="M 400.0000,200.0000 c 0.0000,-110.4569 -89.5431,-200.0000 -200.0000 -200.0000c -110.4569,-0.0000 -200.0000,89.5431 -200.0000 200.0000c -0.0000,110.4569 89.5431,200.0000 200.0000 200.0000c 110.4569,0.0000 200.0000,-89.5431 200.0000 -200.0000Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, both the dashing and fill work for me. What SVG viewer do you use? They're hardly consistent unfortunately, perhaps try outputting pdf instead. — Also, it might be useful to say what version of `diagrams` this is.

Comment: Interesting, in firefox I don't see anything at all! Inkscape has no problems, though (and you can also examine the svg file itself – it's an XML text format after all – and see the circle and dashing is there).

Comment: Please could you be more specific on how you solved the problem in Firefox by 'scaling it up'?

Comment: You can modify SVG while viewing it in Firefox, by pressing ctrl+shift+c. But, for the SVG you've posted I indeed get the same problem you reported, so it's no use. Seems to be indeed a bug in the SVG Diagrams backend.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.  I get different SVG output that looks correct: http://lpaste.net/144030

Comment: I also can't reproduce.  I get a different SVG than the one you posted.  Can you explain the specific steps you used to produce the SVG?

Comment: The steps are as follows: I compile with "cabal install -j" (I'm running in a sandbox) and then run with "dist\build\MyDiagrams\MyDiagrams -o circle.svg -w 400".